# Set Default Color Profile In Mac OS X Leopard

Tags: macos, display, color-profiles

I use an LCD display with my other PC that, for some reason, displays really bright in Leopard.  I change the color profile to calibrate it, but the settings only stick to the user for whom I create the profile.  I'd really like to set that calibrated profile as the default so that at the login screen it is set correctly.

I have tried going in to Console and logging in as root to remove the default colorspace and replace it with the modified one, making sure to name it exactly like the default.  I have chmoded it so that the permissions were the same, but it would not take.

Any ideas how to set the default profile when on the login screen?

Comment: Still nothing ?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely set colour profiles that persist whichever user is logged in, by putting the icc file into /Library/ColorSync/Profiles and then selecting it within the Displays preference panel under Color.

(But I've not really looked to see whether that takes effect within the login screen too. My machines never spend any time there!)

Comment: "I change the color profile to calibrate it, but the settings only stick to the user for whom I create the profile." Your answer is already known.  What is needed is a system wide default color profile.

Comment: When I make a change to a Display's display profile (as me, an 'admin' user) on my 10.5 system, the /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist file gets updated to reflect that change.  All admin users have permissions to create (and delete) files within /Library/Preferences/, hence can update that plist.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
sudo cp ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/.GlobalPreferences.*.plist /private/var/root/Library/Preferences/ByHost/
```

This will copy current user configuration of devices to login window.

It worked for me and it does not even require reboot or logout.

Comment: Wouldn't this copy *all* of those preferences?  Couldn't that be a bit excessive?

Comment: It is a bit excessive. if you know which subset should be copied over to get only the colors right, please, update my answer. Thanks.